# How to understand head->next->next = head; for reverse single list by Recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, linked-list

A signle link list, i want revese it by recursion. but i don't understand the meaning of this line `head->next->next = head;`.

why there need `head->next->next`?

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
```

Here is the implement code:

```
Node* reverseByRecursion(Node *head)
{

    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL) 
        return head;

    Node *newHead = reverseByRecursion(head->next);

    head->next->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;

    return newHead;    
}
```

Comment: I'm with you, I don't understand that too (left aside the chinese comments), that code is completely silly as it appears.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't write such code in C++, use classes (best the standard library). Pick one language for your question! And either that code is your's, in which case you are supposed to knwo what you do. Or it is not your's. Then ask the person you copied it from to explain. Copying code from some website is always a bad idea.

Comment: Without further information (ringlist/terminated), this might invoke undefined behaviour. In general list are not well suited for recursion. Better use iteration.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what are you saying? i don't understand you.

Comment: @BlackMamba So we misunderstood.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ update qustion

Comment: @BlackMamba Still wading on the silly path. Stepping through your code using the debugger might help to solve the mystery.

Answer (score 11):

Let me work with this list.

[image: initial list]

1. `reverseByRecursion(node1)` is called.
2. Neither `node1` nor `node1->next` is `NULL`, so `newHead = reverseByRecursion(head2);` is called.
3. Neither `node2` nor `node2->next` is `NULL`, so `newHead = reverseByRecursion(head3);` is called.
4. `head3->next` is `NULL`, so `head3` is returned from `reverseByRecursion(head2)`.
5. `head = node2` and `head->next = node3`, so `head->next->next = head;` will set `node3->next` to `node2`.
6. `head->next = NULL;` will set `node2->next` to `NULL`. (image 2)
7. `newHead`, which is `node3`, is returned from `reverseByRecursion(head2)`.
8. `head = node1` and `head->next = node2`, so `head->next->next = head;` will set `node2->next` to `node1`.
9. `head->next = NULL;` will set `node1->next` to `NULL`. (image 3)
10. `newHead`, which is `node3`, is returned from `reverseByRecursion(node1)`.
11. Now the list is reversed with having `node3` as the head.

image 2
[image: modified list]

image 3
[image: reversed list]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

try to understand it this way, .next actually meant to change the arrow pointing to the next value. So

`head.next.next = head`

means adding an arrow from the next next position and point it back to head

Hope this is more intuitive to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your base case says that if there are no more elements, then the current node becomes the head of the list.

The head->next->next = head line means that the next node is being reused with its pointer pointing backward (in the opposite direction as before). Since the node used to be the NEXT node after the current node, it becomes the PREVIOUS node before the current head, and its next pointer therefore ought to point to the current node ("head").